# Java Multicasting: How to test on localhost?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, port, multicast

I am trying to implement a multicasting application in Java using a client and a multiple servers. The client would send a datagram through the `MultiacastSocket` and all servers, which would have joined a group should receive the packet. Then all servers should do something and return a unicast answer to the client. Like this: [image]

My implementation looks like this, that the client has a MulticastSocket and the Servers just DatagramSockets. The big question for me is, how do I have to set the group-id of the servers and the portnumbers so that I can test this locally? I tried using different ports on client and servers and the same group-id `localhost`, but this doesn't work.
Also tried `socket.setLoopbackMode()` and `socket.setInterface(InetAddress.getLoopbackAddress())`. But I got stuck somewhere and some constructive input would be great.

Comment: It sounds like you have things backwards. What you send to the multicast group comes from the multicast server, but you have labeled it as the client. The hosts subscribing to the multicast group are the multicast clients. The multicast server sends to the multicast group address as the destination, and the multicast clients subscribe to the multicast group, listening for traffic sent to the multicast group.

Comment: Hey Ron, thanks for the quick answer. I understand that, so the clients (here labeled as TS) and the server (here client) would need a MulticastSocket? All with the same group-address. the single server to send to and the multiple clients to subscribe. But which ports do I have to set ? Can't I do this also using DatagramSockets at the clients? If they are all on localhost, their ports would need to dbe different, or not?

Comment: You send, for example, a single packet to the multicast group, probably using UDP at whatever port you want. The clients will subscribe to the multicast group, and they all hear the same packet with UDP with the same destination port.

Comment: Ok, so the MulticastSocket distributes the single packet to all subscribers. Thanks! This was confusing me and Javadoc wasn't sufficient. Thanks!

Comment: Multicast is an elective broadcast. Broadcast is a problem, and it was eliminated from IPv6 in favor of multicast. Multicast only interrupts the hosts subscribing to the multicast group, but broadcast interrupts all hosts.

Comment: No, the `MulticastSocket` *receives* the packet. You don't need one for sending.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it's dependent on the platform. You could try binding the sending and receiving socket to the loopback interface, but mileage will vary. This trick works for Windows, a little depending on how your network is set up. I got it to work on SUSE Linux after a series of arcane parameter tweaking, but this was at least ten years ago.

The loopback interface *is* special (e.g. usually higher MTU, purely implmented in software, outgoing messages are moved directly into the incoming queue, etc) so sometimes normal networking rules don't apply.

One thing that will work uniformly across platforms it to use a physical network and putting restrictions on the outgoing packet. For testing, a trick I usually employ is to set the TTL for the outgoing packets to 1 (`MulticastSocket.setTimeToLive(1);`). This way, the packet won't make it past any router. Also, you will need to make sure that other testing performed on the same subnet doesn't interfere with yours. I usually use a randomizer for the multicast address for this purpose by generating an address between 224.1.1.1 and 239.254.254.254. That address space should be large enough to avoid collisions. You also need to make sure that your randomizer avoids [reserved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address#Notable_addresses) multicast addresses or all sorts of weird behaviors might start to pop up in your environment.

There is also `MulticastSocket.setLoopbackMode(boolean)`, but I have found it to also be platform-dependent (although not as severe as using the loopback and to be fair, it was some time ago, it might work better now), so some tweaking on the OS might be necessary.